# NotesDocument is locked. Even if the $Writer , $PWriter in the document is deleted.

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

My document can't edit because the document was locked.

display like this...

[image]

but in EZ , It's not contain a field like $Writer , $PWriter

[image]

How to unlock this document?

thank youu !

Answer (score 0):

It just means that some user has this document opened in edit mode and document locking is enabled on that database.
Just tell the user in your dialog to close the document.

You can also disable document locking on the database properties screen:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The locking fields will be set on a replica of the document in the replica database on the 'master locking server' and these fields may not be set on the local document. See this article for details:
https://www.ytria.com/blog/close-inspection-ibm-notes-document-locking-architecture-scanez/